# about intern in java

Tags: java, string-interning

my question is if intern is working with string and string having a
SPC(string pool constant) for it and intern concept also working with integer also,
so is there any integer pool constant?if not then how its working?

```
class InternExample  
{  
 public void print()  
{    
 Integer i=10;  
 Integer j=10;  
 String c="a";  
  String s="a";  
 System.out.println(i==j);// prints true  
 System.out.println(c==s);//prints true  
}  
 public static void main(String args[])  
{  
  new InternExample().print();  
}  
}
```

Comment: read this http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/42276 for Integer

Comment: Loosely related: here's a nasty exploit of auto-boxing in Java, studying it may help you understand auto-boxing better: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Disgruntled-Bomb-Java-Edition.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Added to [@Joachim Sauer's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199165/about-intern-in-java/6199250#6199250) answer, we can ***change the upper bound cache value***.

Some of the options are

1. -Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=value
2. -XX:**AutoBoxCacheMax**=value
3. -XX:+**AggressiveOpts**

**Link** : [Java Specialist](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue191.html)

Answer (score 5):

Auto-boxing uses a cache of common values, as defined in [§ 5.1.7 Boxing Conversion of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.7):

> If the value `p` being boxed is `true`, `false`, a `byte`, a `char` in the range `\u0000` to `\u007f`, or an `int` or `short` number between -128 and 127, then let `r1` and `r2` be the results of any two boxing conversions of `p`. It is always the case that `r1 == r2`.

Note that this is *not* called "interning", however. That term is only used for what is done to `String` literals and what can explicitly be done using [`String.intern()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29).

Answer (score 4):

Beware of your "equality assumptions". For example, with integers:

```
    Integer a = 69;
    Integer b = 69;
    System.out.println(a == b); // prints true
    Integer c = 1000;
    Integer d = 1000;
    System.out.println(c == d); // prints false
```

This is due to the internal implementation of Integer, having pre-existing objects for integer for small values (from -127 to 128 i think). However, for bigger integers, a distinct object Integer will be created each time.

Same goes for your Strings, literal strings in your source code will all be linked to the same object by the compiler ...he's smart enough to do that. However, when you'll read a string from a file, or create/manipulate some string at runtime, they will not be equal anymore.

```
    String a = "x";
    String b = "x";
    String c = new String("x");
    System.out.println(a == b); // prints true
    System.out.println(a == c); // prints false
```